# Warning in odoo v8 when creating payslip for employee

Tags: odoo-8

### I use odoo v8 in Linux server, When I tried to generate payslip for an employee using the HR manager or officer the following message appears:

ValidateError

Field(s) `date_from, date_to` failed against a constraint: Payslip 'Date From' must be before 'Date To'.

Error details:
AccessError
The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.

### (Document type: hr.payslip, Operation: read)

I don't know why this happen I enter the day from 1-April to for example 30 April and the above message appear each time, but if I log in as an admin everything is working fine.
I don't know is it a bug in this version of odoo or not and how i can fixed it.
Thank you

Comment: Change the rights for the specific user (the non-admin). This user doesn't have enough access rights for the module.

Comment: Thank you Yenthe  for your comment but can you explain more , I gave the non admin user  access  right for the administration and for HR Module i gave them officer and manager but still not work

Comment: Every user in Odoo has rights (under settings > users > select a user). When the user does not have enough rights for a specific module / view it cannot access the view and the user will get warnings as you do. So you will need to give the correct user the correct rights under settings > users.

Comment: Yes , I understand what you mean, i use HR manager and i gave him for administration = access right and for HR = manager , and the other options are having the default value . I made many changes in the setting but still not working

Answer (score 0):

only employee whose payslip it is can edit or create it or the manager of the department where employee belongs to can edit it
https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/access-denied-with-payslip-28246